# Testing to see if a string contains any of a set of other strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I am trying to test if a url leads to an image, such as "http://i.imgur.com/vLsht.jpg"
by testing to see if the string contains ".jpg" or ".png" or ".gif" etc.

My curent code is:

```
if (stripos($row_rsjustpost['link'], ".png") !== false) {
//do stuff
}
```

I would like to do something like

```
if (stripos($row_rsjustpost['link'], ".png" || ".jpg" || ".gif") !== false) {
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: The file extension does not truthfully indicate if a file is an "image" or not.  Are you sure you want to rely on your method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an okay use of a regular expression via [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('/\.(png|jpg|gif)/i', $row_rsjustpost['link'], $matches) {
    // Contains one or more of them...   
}

// $matches holds the matched extension if one was found.
print_r($matches);
```

Note: if the string must occur at the end like a file extension, terminate it with `$`:

```
/\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i
//-------------^^
```

If you were attempting to locate only one substring, it would be more appropriate to use `stripos()`, but you can match a number of different patterns with a regex, without having to cough out a long if/else chain.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't want to use regular expressions, here's how I'd do it:

Get the last 4 characters (the file extension)

```
$filepath = $row_rsjustpost['link'];
$extension = substr($filepath, length($filepath) - 4);
```

Then see if it matches a pattern:

```
if (in_array($extension, array(".png", ".jpg", ".gif"))) {
   // Have a party!
}
```